# Print 4 letter combinations of a string without using lists or itertools

Tags: python, list, iteration

we are to write a function that takes a single parameter string, and then outputs each 4 letter permutation from the possible combinations of the string. so for example even if it is a 5 letter word you have to return all 4 letter combinations of the string. it can also only be solved iteratively so no recursion.

currently i've tried using nested for loops, so for instance

```
for i in word:
    for x in word:
        for z in word:
            for y in word:
                print(y)
            print(z)
        print(x)
    print(i)
```

However the issue i'm coming across is that firstly, i'm not sure on how I would concatenate these outputs into a single string output given that i cannot use lists or any form of sets/dictionaries/tuples etc. secondly, how exactly would i avoid duplicate strings?

Comment: if `word="abcd"` you have to print 'aaaa' or only the word with one letter `a` (for example `"acdb", "cadb"`, and so on)? And the same question is about the other letters (`b`, `c` and `d`).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a `+` operator to join two strings together:

```
a = 'str1'
b = 'str2'
c = a + b
print(c)
```

output:

```
'st1str2'
```

So you can use this to join together i, x, z and y into one string, and print it as 1 'word'.

Comment: ahh thank you for that, for some reason i imagined that wouldn't have worked but now i've got that issue out of the way. while i hope not to be insistent, but would you have some idea for how i could approach the issue of getting rid of duplicate strings and managing to extract all 4 letter combinations from it?

Comment: @agni_ka1 without using lists or similar, I have no idea sorry

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear so I suppose that for `word='abcd'` you have to print the words: `'abcd', 'aabc', aaab'` and so on.
I suppose that a single letter can be present more than one time in the different combinations of letters (permutation of the letters 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd').

In this condition try code below:

```
def permutation(word):
    counter = 1
    for i in word:
        for x in word:
            for z in word:
                for y in word:
                    print(f"{counter} - {i + x + z + y}")
                    counter += 1

permutation("abcd")
```

The output contains 256 strings of 4 letters that are the 4^4 permutation of the 4 letters.

Comment: This will miss out a lot of combinations due to the filtering of the words, for example y will always be the letter d, so all your outputs will end in d